# Cursor not working corretly on Html Select Option Microsoft EDGE

Tags: html, microsoft-edge

I am not getting default cursor when is open page on EDGE. 
It shows the cursor of the div below the option.
Its working fine on Chrome and Firefox.
Issue can be verified by creating html from code below and open in both edge and chrome. See difference in pointers when we move on options.

```
    <select>
        <option value="">Select a Value</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
        <option value="TestValue1">TestValue1</option>
    </select>

    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div style="width:50%;height:200px;background-color:gray;text-align:center;margin-top:0px;cursor:pointer;">
        <div style="clear:both;margin-top:100px;display:inline-block;">This area has different pointer</div>
            <div>
```

It may be a bug in EDGE or am i missing some code? Any help would be really appreciated.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/f7f3yh2a/

Comment: Can you setup a small repro of the issue on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @Sampson Added jsfiddle link added. Open link in edge and chrome, you will see difference in pointer when we hover on dropdown list. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can use `div * { cursor:pointer; }` to make sure it works on childrens too?

Comment: @julmot i want the similar behavior as its on chrome. It should not show {cursor:pointer} on dropdown list.

Comment: Did you tried using z-index on that element where the cursor should not be pointer?

Comment: @julmot z-index not working.